# datepicker translation to other languages

Tags: java, gxt

I have this date field with uibinder.

```
<form:DateField ui:field="Importation" editable="false" allowBlank="true"/>

  private static final String    DATE_FIELD_FORMAT   = "yyyy-MMMM-dd";

  @Path("Importation")
  @UiField(provided = true)
  DateField    dImportation  = new DateField(new DateTimePropertyEditor(DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DATE_FIELD_FORMAT)));
```

With this date field, I have the right format of date, it show me 2013-Décembre-04 (french), and that it is what I want.

The problem is that when I click on the little calendar, it shows almost perfecly. Everything is in english but the button "Today" is "Aujourd'hui" like it should.

My question is how can I make the whole calendar in french: the **months names** and the **days of the week letters**?

In addition, I have checked my locale info, it is `fr_CA`(french_canadian), and I even tried `fr_FR`(french france) and even russian. The result is always the same, the "Today" button is in the good language but the rest is in english.

```
  LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName().toString(); it return fr_CA
```

I have put those line in myapp.gwt.xml

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="fr_CA"/>
<set-property name="locale" value="fr_CA"/>
```

what else can I do?

example:

[image: The datePicker]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
DateField df;
    df.getDatePicker().setMessages(new DatePicker.DatePickerMessages() {
        @Override public String cancelText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String maxText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String minText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String monthYearText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String nextText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String okText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String prevText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String todayText() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override public String todayTip(String s) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```